# Regex URL - replace matches by links

Tags: c#, regex

I try to code a regex for URL (with replace) respecting these points :

- **http://www.test.com** is correct
  => `<a href="http://www.test.com">www.test.com</a>`
- **https://www.test.com** is correct
  => `<a href="https://www.test.com">www.test.com</a>`
- **http://test.com** is correct
  => `<a href="http://test.com">test.com</a>`
- **www.test.com** is correct
  => `<a href="http://www.test.com">www.test.com</a>`
- test.com is incorrect

What I have done :

```
// __url__ is the rest of the regex but NOT IMPORTANT in my problem
var regex = new Regex(@"((https?:\/\/)?(?<URL>www\." + __url__ + "))");
regex.Replace("www.test.com", "<a href=\"http://${URL}\">${URL}</a>");
```

Some problems here :

```
- Test 1 OK
- Test 2 KO
  I force http as protocol
- Test 3 KO
- Test 4 OK
```

Comment: Have you tested your regex on https://regex101.com/ ?

Comment: Yes, I have tested... in fact I have no problem to make it matching but it's with the replacement I bug :)... I know it doesn't match with case 3 but it's just because I have adapted it to make the replacement OK in almost cases

Comment: By the way, I don't think regex101.com uses .net regex. Since regex parsing is not standart for every language, the results *may* be different in c# and other languages. Keep in mind that.

Comment: Try `Regex.Replace(s,@"(?:(https?:\/\/)|(www\.))(\S+)", m=>
 m.Groups[1].Success ? string.Format("<a href="{0}{1}{2}">{1}{2}</a>", m.Groups[1].Value,m.Groups[2].Value,m.Groups[3].Value) :
 string.Format("<a href="http://{0}{1}">{0}{1}</a>", m.Groups[2].Value,m.Groups[3].Value)
)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may capture either the protocol or the `www.` part to make either obligatory (with `(?:(https?:\/\/)|(www\.))`). That way, you will avoid matching `test.com`. Then, you will just need to use a dynamic replacing logic inside a match evaluator:

```
var inputs = new[] {"http://www.test.com",  "https://www.test.com", "http://test.com", "www.test.com","test.com" };
foreach (var s in inputs)
{
    var res = Regex.Replace(s,@"(?:(https?:\/\/)|(www\.))(\S+)", m => 
        m.Groups[1].Success ? 
            string.Format("<a href=\"{0}{1}{2}\">{1}{2}</a>", m.Groups[1].Value,m.Groups[2].Value,m.Groups[3].Value) : 
            string.Format("<a href=\"http://{0}{1}\">{0}{1}</a>", m.Groups[2].Value,m.Groups[3].Value) 
        );
    Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", s, res);
}
```

See the [C# online demo](http://ideone.com/9atubL)

Output:

```
http://www.test.com => <a href="http://www.test.com">www.test.com</a>
https://www.test.com => <a href="https://www.test.com">www.test.com</a>
http://test.com => <a href="http://test.com">test.com</a>
www.test.com => <a hr
```

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I wanted... I didn't know this kind of syntax to replace dynamically inside the match evaluator... Perfect !!!